# Adding Access-Control-Max-Age to Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

In order to prevent OPTIONS preflight requests being sent to an Azure Function, I want to add the `Access-Control-Max-Age` header to the OPTIONS response so that the browser caches the response for a given time.

I tried to create an Azure Proxy Function with this proxies.json file:

```
{
    "proxies": {
        "AddCacheHeaderToCorsPreflightResponse": {
            "debug": true,
            "matchCondition": {
                "methods": [
                    "OPTIONS",
                    "GET"
                ],
                "route": "/api/{rest}"
            },
            "backendUri": "http://%WEBSITE_HOSTNAME%/api/{rest}",
            "responseOverrides": {
                "response.headers.Access-Control-Max-Age": "31536000"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this fails to add the response header to the OPTIONS request, but, for testing purposes, I can get GET responses to return the header. It appears that Azure doesn't allow you to add proxy functions for OPTIONS requests.

Is there a way to do this in Azure?

Comment: Have you found solution?

Comment: @AlexanderMujirishvili No I never found a solution to this problem. But there's a chance that there is now a solution since its been over a year since I originally searched for a solution and Azure is constantly evolving.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your `function.json` contains `OPTIONS` in the `methods` array, like so:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "methods": ["get", "post", "options"]
    }
  ]
}
```

When you configure your httptrigger function, click Integrate and choose the `OPTIONS` method. Alternatively, you can remove the `methods` array entirely and allow all methods.

Comment: I may be wrong Joey Cai but I believe that `function.json` applies to normal Azure Functions, not Azure proxy functions. I'm not sure if that is what you are suggesting. Unless you are suggesting that the functions that the proxy is running for must also bind to "options", which if that is what you are suggesting, then I have also tried that too.

Comment: I suggest that you function also bind to `options`.